# Cygwin SFTP server works fine with WinSCP, but Linux client shows "connection reset by peer"

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin, sftp

Using Cygwin, I configured an SFTP server on a Windows 7 machine. I can use WinSCP for file transferring from another Windows machine, but when I try to log in to the machine from a Linux machine it doesn't work. It comes with an error saying “connection reset by peer”.

I am not sure what to do to get it working. If anyone could help me out, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which command are you using from Linux?

Comment: Which ftp server is running? What do it s logs tell you?

Comment: on the terminal I run "sftp <accountname>@<hostname>